# using TDCH "batch.insert" mode, Transaction ABORTed due to deadlock error

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata

I am using batch insert mode of TDCH to move data from Hadoop to Teradata. The job runs for sometime but then breaks down with " Transaction ABORTed due to deadlock". The data is about 10M rows. I was using 3 mappers, that was giving the error. 
I ran the same job with 1 mapper and it succeeded. Is there any option by which deadlocks can be stopped ? 
The TDCH job type is "hcat". Hive version is 1.2.1.
TDCH version : 1.4.3. TD DB version : 15.

Comment: Deadlock timeouts are 240 seconds by default on Teradata. It can be incresaed by your DBA by simply adjusting a DBS Control setting. That being said, it is best to determine why TDCH is causing a deadlock with multiple mappers. Are you loading a PI or NOPI table in Teradata? What is your export batch size?

Comment: It is a PI table. I am not assigning a batch size. TDCH is taking it by default.
Is there any way to find out the batch size ? I don't see it in the logs.

Comment: Default batch size should be 10K. Is the PI unique or non-unique? Curious if the write lock is getting hung up with duplicate values on the same AMP. (Just an idea at this point)